# selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Failed to start browser /snap/firefox/current/firefox.launcher

Tags: python, linux, selenium, geckodriver

I am trying to open Firefox with this simple program in python, I am using the latest version of Ubuntu.

```
from selenium import webdriver

brow = webdriver.Firefox()
```

But I am getting the error message,
"selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Failed to start browser /snap/firefox/current/firefox.launcher: no such file or directory"

I have tried updating firefox and using a different geckodriver.

Comment: Are you sure the firefox driver is installed in the right directory?

Answer (score 5):

The error is most likely [a bug in GeckoDriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/2062) causing it to try to find Firefox inside Snap instead of the default location `/usr/bin/firefox`, because the script has been run from PyCharm that was installed through Snap.

To solve the issue, you have to unset the Snap environment variables before running the script. Actually, I found out that only two variables must be unset: `SNAP_NAME` and `SNAP_INSTANCE_NAME`:

```
$ unset SNAP_NAME
$ unset SNAP_INSTANCE_NAME
```

Answer (score 2):

Surely you should take a good look at the paths you enter, however, i recommend a generic approach.

You can use a [webdriver-manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/#use-with-firefox) that takes care of any problems in this respect automatically and in any supported operating system

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
```

N.B.: this is compatible with Selenium 4.x and below.

Comment: I have the same problem and I am already using `webdriver-manager`. Actually, this problem happens only when I launch the script from PyCharm installed through Snap. When I launch the script using a terminal outside PyCharm it works. Not sure where is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When using Selenium through PyCharm for the first time, I got the same error. Solved this problem very simply. Let's try next:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary('your_path_to_firefox')

brow = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
```

Let me know if it helped you too ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options= webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/firefox" <-- Can be modified per your setting
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```