# SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Failed to start browser /snap/firefox/current/firefox.launcher: no such file or directory Python Linux

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

browser = Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
```

I tried to change path, also adding services:

```
browser = Firefox(service=Service(executable_path='/home/karina/snap/geckodriver'))
```

What the problem with my code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Failed to start browser /snap/firefox/current/firefox.launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74376177/selenium-common-exceptions-sessionnotcreatedexception-message-failed-to-start)

Comment: No,I tried to do that, but it still do not work

Comment: try the symlink solution from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/2062